# How to use AWS S3 CLI to dump files to stdout in BASH?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm starting a bash script which will take a path in S3 (as specified to the [ls](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ls.html) command) and dump the contents of all of the file objects to `stdout`. Essentially I'd like to replicate `cat /path/to/files/*` except for S3, e.g. `s3cat '/bucket/path/to/files/*'`. My first inclination looking at the options is to use the `cp` command to a temporary file and then `cat` that.

Has anyone tried this or similar or is there already a command I'm not finding which does it?

Comment: I use PHP and the Services_Amazon_S3 class to do similar things.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

> dump the contents of all of the file objects to stdout.

You can accomplish this if you pass `-` for destination of `aws s3 cp` command. 
For example,  `$ aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/stream.txt -`.

What you're trying to do is something like this? ::

```
#!/bin/bash

BUCKET=YOUR-BUCKET-NAME
for key in `aws s3api list-objects --bucket $BUCKET --prefix bucket/path/to/files/ | jq -r '.Contents[].Key'`
do
  echo $key
  aws s3 cp s3://$BUCKET/$key - | md5sum
done
```

Comment: Note however that '-' as a placeholder for stdout does not work in all the versions of awscli. For example, the version 1.2.9, which comes with ubuntu LTS 14.04.2, doesn't support it.

Comment: Ditto that.  I'm on Ubuntu 12.x, and it does not work in my instance of bash.

Comment: Problem with this is that you can't get a specific version of the file.

Comment: not working on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 either (`aws --version`: `aws-cli/1.15.40 Python/3.6.5 Darwin/17.7.0 botocore/1.10.40`)

Comment: this answer has also the advantage that the file content will be stream to your terminal, and not copied as a whole. see more at https://loige.co/aws-command-line-s3-content-from-stdin-or-to-stdout/#pipeline-processing-of-s3-files

Answer (score 77):

If you are using a version of the AWS CLI that doesn't support copying to "-" you can also use /dev/stdout:

```
$ aws s3 cp --quiet s3://mybucket/stream.txt /dev/stdout
```

You also may want the `--quiet` flag to prevent a summary line like the following from being appended to your output:

> download: s3://mybucket/stream.txt to ../../dev/stdout

Answer (score 6):

You can try using [s3streamcat](https://pypi.org/project/s3streamcat/), it supports bzip, gzip and xz formats as well.

**Install with**

`sudo pip install s3streamcat`

**Usage:**

```
s3streamcat s3://bucketname/dir/file_path
s3streamcat s3://bucketname/dir/file_path | more
s3streamcat s3://bucketname/dir/file_path | grep something
```

Answer (score -4):

If you wish to accomplish this using BASH, you'll have to call-out to an external app such as the [AWS Command-Line Interface](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) (CLI). It does not have a CAT equivalent, so you would need to copy the file locally and then CAT it.

Alternatively, you could use/write an app that directly calls the AWS SDK, which is available for languages such as Python, PHP, Java. By using the SDK, file contents can be retrieved in-memory and then sent to stdout.

Comment: The above answer lists that you can use 'cp' with '-' as the 2nd file argument to make it output the file to stdout.

Answer (score -5):

Ah ha!

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/s3cat/1.0.8

I'm writing more characters to satisfy the length requirement.