# How to retrieve values of an object from a Amazon S3 bucket using command line?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

Let's say we have 3 objects inside a bucket in s3:

- object 1 which has value 10,
- object 2 which has value 20,
- object 3 which has value 30.

Does anyone know how to retrieve those values using command line?

The command `$ aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name` gives a list of all the objects, but I'm unable to find any command which lists all the values **inside** the objects.

Comment: Are you looking for this [how-to-use-aws-s3-cli-to-dump-files-to-stdout-in-bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28330907/how-to-use-aws-s3-cli-to-dump-files-to-stdout-in-bash)?

Comment: Can you provide more information about your use-case? Normally, objects are downloaded from Amazon S3 to the local filesystem and the files are accessed from there.

Comment: Normally, data kept in Amazon S3 is in the form of Files. If you are looking for a traditional key-value store that is mostly used to store numerical values and strings, take a look at Amazon DynamoDB.

Answer (score 1):

`aws s3 cp s3://bucket/filename.ext /dev/stdout` will dump the contents to your console